# Redis Perl Library: how to use sorted sets?

Tags: perl, redis, cpan, sortedset

I have a data structure in `redis` that uses sorted sets for a "top items" system that I plan to use on my webpage. I am basically using the `redis-cli` commands like [`ZRANGE`](http://redis.io/commands/zrange) to get my top items out of redis.

Now I want to access this data programmatically in Perl. I have seen the [Redis.pm library](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Redis/lib/Redis.pm), but I could not find any signs of these `Z*` methods there.

Can I use the Redis.pm library to work with sorted sets in redis or do I have to use another library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the Z* commands with Redis.pm

Actually, all the Redis commands are mapped in the Perl API, even if some of them are not documented. This is done through the [AUTOLOAD feature](http://perl.active-venture.com/pod/perltoot-autoload.html) of Perl.

The definition of the parameters of the commands follows the Redis documentation, except if the Redis.pm documentation states otherwise.

See this example in the non-regression testing scripts:

https://github.com/melo/perl-redis/blob/master/t/01-basic.t#L195